# Где находится основной цикл программы Windows Forms CLR c++

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli, clr

Мне нужно создать небольшое десктоп приложение на c++. Написал программу, используя Windows Forms.
Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно анализировать клавиши, нажимаемые пользователем в процессе работы (а точнее при нажатии esc должна выполнятся функция ClearAll(), а при Enter – ShowResult), а я не знаю как.

MyForm.h

```
#pragma once
#include <cmath>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
const double PI = 3.141592653589793;
namespace ADMCalc {
 

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Сводка для MyForm
/// </summary>
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Освободить все используемые ресурсы.
    /// </summary>
    ~MyForm()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label3;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ label4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox4;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ button2;
protected:

private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Обязательная переменная конструктора.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;


#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Требуемый метод для поддержки конструктора — не изменяйте 
        /// содержимое этого метода с помощью редактора кода.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->textBox4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(118, 91);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(19, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->label1->Text = L"d1";
            this->label1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::label1_Click);
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(118, 143);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(19, 13);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 1;
            this->label2->Text = L"d2";
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(143, 88);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(150, 20);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(143, 136);
            this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(150, 20);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 3;
            this->textBox2->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::textBox2_TextChanged);
            // 
            // textBox3
            // 
            this->textBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(380, 88);
            this->textBox3->Name = L"textBox3";
            this->textBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(150, 20);
            this->textBox3->TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this->label3->AutoSize = true;
            this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(362, 95);
            this->label3->Name = L"label3";
            this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(19, 13);
            this->label3->TabIndex = 5;
            this->label3->Text = L"Δx";
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this->label4->AutoSize = true;
            this->label4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(362, 143);
            this->label4->Name = L"label4";
            this->label4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(19, 13);
            this->label4->TabIndex = 7;
            this->label4->Text = L"Δz";
            // 
            // textBox4
            // 
            this->textBox4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(380, 136);
            this->textBox4->Name = L"textBox4";
            this->textBox4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(150, 20);
            this->textBox4->TabIndex = 6;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(204, 257);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(107, 40);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 8;
            this->button1->Text = L"Enter";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(343, 257);
            this->button2->Name = L"button2";
            this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(107, 40);
            this->button2->TabIndex = 9;
            this->button2->Text = L"Clear";
            this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button2_Click);
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(668, 390);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"ADM";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();
 
        }
#pragma endregion       
    bool protect() {
        if ((textBox1->Text->Length == 0) || (textBox2->Text->Length == 0)) return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox1->Text->Length; i++)
            if (!(('0' <= textBox1->Text[i]) && ('9' >= textBox1->Text[i])  || (textBox1->Text[i] == '-')  || (textBox1->Text[i] == ','))) return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox2->Text->Length; i++)
            if (!(('0' <= textBox2->Text[i]) && ('9' >= textBox2->Text[i])  || (textBox2->Text[i] == '-') || (textBox2->Text[i] == ','))) return false;
        return true;
    }
    void ClearAll() {
        textBox1->Text = "";
        textBox2->Text = "";
        textBox3->Text = "";
        textBox4->Text = "";
    }
    void ShowAll() {
        double d1, d2, dx, dz, sinn, coss;
        d1 = System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);
        d2 = System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox2->Text);
        sinn = sin(20 * PI / 180);
        coss = cos(20 * PI / 180);
        dx = (d2 - d1) / (2 * sinn);
        dz = (d2 + d1) / (2 * (coss - 1));
        textBox3->Text = System::Convert::ToString(dx);
        textBox4->Text = System::Convert::ToString(dz);
    }
    private: System::Void label1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    }
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        if (protect()) ShowAll();
        else MessageBox::Show("Ошибка ввода", "Ошибка");
    }
    private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        ClearAll();
    }
    private: System::Void textBox2_TextChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        
    }
};
}
```

MyForm.cpp

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace ADMCalc
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int) {
 
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
 
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
 
    Application::Run(gcnew MyForm);
 
    return 0;
}
```

[image: MyForm.h]

Где находится основной цикл выполнения программы и можно ли его изменять(добавить анализ клавиш)?
Или мне нужно вообще не так делать? В таком случае, скажите, пожалуйста, где и что почитать, чтобы понять что и как делать.

Comment: [WndProc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: [PreviewKeyDown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=netframework-4.8)